# Extrude along three edges

Tags: modeling, edges, extrude

I am currently learning how to use Blender. I want to extrude this upper face along the three edges so that it extrudes into the tip of a pyramid, if that makes sense.

Hope you understand what I mean and can help me!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's an extrusion, but there is an extension.. sliding those vertices along their edges, beyond the edges' original extents. That would be <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, either holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd>, or hitting <kbd>C</kbd>, to release the clamp.

The slide won't automatically stop at the point of the pyramid.. it can  go beyond it .. that may not be what you want.

Comment: That works well, thank you.

Comment: @Leander :: There is a strange tradition here that if this is the correct solution, we are supposed to press the correct-check sign under the answer.